# Bootstrap/resampling and bayesian regression, solving dependency problems

Tags: regression, bayesian, logistic, resampling

Let's say we have two experiment replications R1 and R2, (with some modifications in R2), deployed for intersecting (but not fully the same, let's say >50% but <80%) populations of participants at different time points.

We fit a Bayesian regression to R1 data and want to improve our estimates using R2 and fitting regression with R1 posteriors as R2 priors for shared factors in R1 and R2.

As R1 and R2 populations intersect, what are the potential consequences of that for R2 posteriors?

I assume we might have too narrow CI (same people appearing in dataset twice with similar reactions)? Are there ways to estimate that?

Also, does it make sense to resample R2 dataset to increase variability before fitting the model?

Fit only to R2 participants who didn’t participate in R1 (provided this is a high enough number)?

Or increase priors weight?

Potential specifications for a multilevel version are also appreciated, but the sample size in R1/R2 is limited and I’m afraid the multilevel solution might be underpowered, undermining the idea of aggregating two studies.

Comment: It would be easier to give advice if you would be more explicit about the models and the data involved.